# Proving that $T(t)x$ is in the domain

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

$(T(t))_{t\ge 0}$ is a $C_{0}$-semigroup on a Banach space $X$ with generator $A:D(A)\subset X\to X$. For $k\ge 2$, define

$$D(A^{k}):=\{x\in D(A^{k-1})|A^{k-1}x\in D(A)\}$$

I want to show that for any $x\in X$ such that $x\in D(A^{k})$ for some integer $k\ge 2$

$$T(t)x\in D(A^{k})$$

for all $t\ge 0$.

I know that if $x\in D(A)$, then $T(t)x\in D(A)$ for all $t\ge 0$, with $\frac{d}{dt}T(t)x=T(t)Ax=AT(t)x$ for all $t\ge 0$.

Is it simply a case of proving that property for $A^{k}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use induction on $k\mbox{}$.

Comment: @user3482534: That isn't what I would do.  If $x \in D(A^2)$ then $Ax \in D(A)$, so applying your sentence "I know that" with $x$ replaced by $Ax$, you get $T(t) Ax \in D(A)$.  But $T(t) A x = A T(t) x$ so you have $A T(t) x \in D(A)$, which means $T(t) x \in D(A^2)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge It has been a long time since I used proof by induction. Would I next have to prove the property for some $k>2$ and then $k+1>2$ (which would then imply it holds for all $k\ge 2$)?

Comment: So for $k=n$, for some $n>2$, we have

$$D(A^{n})=\{x\in D(A^{n-1})|A^{n-1}x\in D(A)\}$$

Then for $x\in D(A^{2})$, we have $A^{n-1}x\in D(A)$. So $T(t)A^{n-1}x\in D(A)$.

So I have to show $T(t)A^{n-1}x=A^{n-1}T(t)x$?

Comment: Oh, I never noticed that $A^{n}T(t)x=T(t)A^{n}x$ for $x\in D(A^{n})$ and $t\ge 0$.